# How do I kill strace without killing the process being traced?

Tags: linux, strace

I am attempting to debug the startup of an application. I would like to use `strace` to get a trace of the system calls carried out by the application during its startup, but once the application has started I don't want the performance overhead of `strace`.

If you run `strace` normally:

```
strace -f myprogram
```

then if you attempt to kill `strace`, it will take `myprogram` down with it.

You can attach `strace` to a running process as follows:

```
strace -f -p <myprogram pid>
```

but then it is hard to get a trace of the application's startup.

Is there a way to capture a trace of an application's startup, and then detach strace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One method is to use the `-D` flag of `strace`, which runs the `strace` process as a descendant of the process being traced.

For example:

```
strace -f -D myprogram
```

will start tracing `myprogram`. Now running:

```
killall strace
```

will kill the `strace` process, but `myprogram` will continue to run.

Comment: You can also start the app, then attach strace with `strace -p <PID>`. Obviously, this won't trace the app startup, but this can be handy for other things like "turn on tracing during this test HTTP request".